# How do you link both spark and kafka in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I need to use symbols from the kafka project in spark (to use the DefaultDecoder rather than the StringDecoder). Since these symbols are in kafka I need to link both kafka and spark in my sbt project. Here is reduced sbt file that isolates my exact problem:

```
name := """spark-kafka"""                                                                                           

version := "1.0"                                                                                                         

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"                                                                                                 

lazy val root = (project in file("."))                                                                                   

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(                                                                                             
  "org.apache.kafka"           % "kafka_2.10"           % "0.8.2.0",                                                     
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",                                                       
  "org.apache.spark"              %% "spark-core"       % "1.2.1" % "provided"                                           
)
```

If I try and build this with sbt compile, I get this error:

```
> compile
[info] Updating {file:/home/rick/go/src/defend7/sparksprint/tools/consumer/}root...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed Feb 21, 2015 1:37:05 PM
```

This is the same error I get in my less-isolated larger sbt project so that is why I think this smaller sbt file has isolated just the problem I am facing.

I have tried to understand what 'data' sbt is talking about in 'impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded' and have also tried some of the common remedies (such as explicitly including slf4j-api 1.6.1 in my libraryDependencies) but this has gotten me nowhere so far.

I'm really stuck and would be very grateful for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a conflict resolution problem somewhere deep in Ivy. It might be fixed by manually excluding `slf4j` dependency from Kafka and explicitly adding dependency on latest version:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(                                                                                             
  "org.apache.kafka"           % "kafka_2.10"           % "0.8.2.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j")
  ),                                                     
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",      
  "org.slf4j"                  % "slf4j-api"            % "1.7.10", 
  "org.apache.spark"           %% "spark-core"          % "1.2.1" % "provided"                                           
)
```

Comment: This did let me resolve the linking problem, but I ran into further linking problems after getting past this one. I have resorted to using Base64 encoding/decoding for now rather than trying to get Spark to stop using the StringDecoders. Thanks for the help.